# PDO basic select query

Tags: mysql, pdo

I'm learning PDO and try to make a query:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM hallinta 
                        WHERE username = :user AND hash = :hash");
$stmt->bindParam(':user', $myusername);
$stmt->bindParam(':hash', $hash);
    $stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->rowCount();
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $r=$row["hash"];
}
```

Works fine with only one WHERE statement, but when both :user and :hash is in query I will get error

> ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

What is wrong in query?

Comment: Sorry, error message as whole :"ERROR: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"

Answer (score 0):

For some extremely strange reason you omit the most meaningful part of the error message, which actually were pointing out to the error.

But nevertheless, this is not PDO error but SQL error. You are supposed to **test your queries in a console first**, and then use in PDO only a tested one.

Also, you have to pay more attention to the queries you run. There are no syntax errors in one you posted here.